# how to hide .php and id on url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to change this URL:

```
http://example.com/pages.php?sports_id=23
```

into this:

```
http://example.com/pages/sports/23
```

**My code is:**

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1\.php


ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your .htacess

```
RewriteRule ^pages$ pages.php [L]
```

But I think it will not be possible to change the GET part to a slash.
(Correct me if I am wrong).

Comment: MegaXLR I did not understand ?

Comment: I have tried all the Rewrite lines in my .htaccess but nothing happened. It shows error and shows the url like:

http://domain.com/pages/?p_id=39&p_title=Christine%20Lagarde

Comment: How is the `/sports/23` part of the URL handled by this directive?

Comment: the url is still same like :
http://domain.com/pages.php?id=22

i am using this in my link:
<a href="pages.php?id='.$id.'&title='.$title.'">

Comment: @FhdKaxi You should be using the "pretty" URL in your link. ie. `<a href="/pages/sports/23">`. You then use the code in .htaccess to rewrite this "pretty" URL into the real (ugly) URL.

Comment: you are saying    ( RewriteRule ^pages$ pages.php [L]  )   in .htaccess and <a href="/pages/sports/23"> in link ?

Comment: Yes, except the directive above is not correct.

Comment: I updated .htaccess as : ......

RewriteRule ^pages$ pages.php [L] ...... and Link on my php page as : .... <a href="/pages/sports/23"> ...... But still its not working and it did not show my the page and error on page occurs. Please guide me as I am new at php

Comment: As I have stated, it will not be possible to make the GET part a part of the URL which means you woll always be stuck with the question mark in the page. However, making changes to your .htaccess does **not** change the `<a>` tags in your php file. you need to explicitly change them to the requested location yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already, you first need to *change* the URLs in your application to the form `/pages/sports/23`. You then use .htaccess to rewrite the "pretty" URL back to the real URL.

To literally rewrite `/pages/sports/23` back into `/pages.php?sports_id=23` then you can do something like:

```
RewriteRule ^pages/sports/23$ pages.php?sports_id=23 [L]
```

However, you probably want something more generic. But how generic? It's not clear from your question which elements are variable. Something like the following *might* work for you...

```
RewriteRule ^([^/])+/([^/])+/(\d{3})+$ $1.php?$2_id=$3 [L]
```